# Java Web Service Using Dii method

Tags: java, web-services

Hi Friends i am new to web services and now i want to create a web service and consume other webservices to my project. i went through lot of search and find out that for consuming web service Dynamic Invocation Interface (DII) is best method. i find out how to create webservice using this link http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html. But for consuming other webservices apart from that i have created using DII i dont know can any one please tell some material with examples to test it, and also regarding how to secure webservice .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop following web services with java

1. SOAP/WDSL
2. Restful

Both of these two services have their own strengths and weaknesses. Just search for "soap vs restful" and you'll find lots of articles to read on this subject and hopefully you will then have the ability to decide which should be implemented where.

Here are some useful links which have recently helped me with developing web services.

- [www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp)
- [netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html)
   This is to develop a restful service. You can use jersey library from java.net for the implementation or include it using the netbeans modules.
- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html